# The meaning of being "impartial" in this website

Tags: discussion

> If we don't believe in freedom of expression for people we despise, we don't believe in it at all. – Noam Chomsky

[A question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/30384/why-doesnt-israel-want-an-independent-investigation-of-gaza-2018-border-events) entitled "Why doesn't Israel want an independent investigation of Gaza 2018 border events?" was closed because the moderator Philipp and someone else claimed that "the primary purpose of this question appears to be to promote or discredit a specific political cause, group or politician." (many such cases can be found on this website regarding Israel.)

[Another question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/4481/why-wont-israel-just-capture-palestine) entitled "Why won't Israel just capture Palestine?" which says "Israel has lost 1500+ people. So there is surely a reason to capture Palestine" is still open.

[Another case](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/4524/was-there-any-official-condemnation-of-hamas-over-use-of-civilians-and-especiall)
Quote: "There is ample proof that Hamas is using Palestinian civilians - even children - as human shields... [This] violates both Geneva convention and any form of human decency." Can any honest and aware person just imagine that somebody can ask a question with this tone about the crimes committed by Israel and UK in Palestine?

I'm leaving this website, but out of curiosity I want to ask: what is the definition of being "impartial" here? (Please don't insult the intelligence of the readers)

Comment: Frankly the 2nd question is more of the naive kind that many people ask on this site: why doesn't country X invade Y etc. Given that the OP hails from India he probably has a Kashmir-like "solution" in mind. He seemed quite unaware that Israel had already tried something like that in Gaza. I guess the death toll from Kashmir is not well conveyed in Indian media.

Comment: @Fizz, another example: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/4524/was-there-any-official-condemnation-of-hamas-over-use-of-civilians-and-especiall. Quote: "There is ample proof that Hamas is using Palestinian civilians - even children - as human shields." Can any honest and aware person just imagine that somebody can ask a question with this tone about the crimes committed by Israel and UK in Palestine?

Comment: You can't even ask about the roots of Israel here with a skeptic tone: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/26779/on-what-basis-do-western-countries-consider-israel-a-legitimate-country

Comment: The problem with the closed question isn't the content of it: there is a question there that could reasonably be asked on this site IMHO. But the phrasing and time of the que are clearly completely partisan

Answer (score 0):

Chomsky isn't a filter for quality, but for content. Sometimes the two overlap - despised content is often (or sometimes?) of low quality; but it's important to guard against assuming that pleasantly presented earnest "right on" content is always of reasonable quality and erudition, when some of it can be utterly specious, but be given undue weight due to the power associated with particular views, such as in the worlds of cultural, journalistic and academic products and services. 
Reminds me of the way that people with a northern working-class accent can be treated as less intelligent than those with cut glass effete home counties accents, when on inspection the reverse can be true. Same goes for "left-wing" v "right-wing" views.

Comment: Chomsky is not an expert on politics.  Using his name on a Question/Answer site which solicits expert opinions immediately raises the "pushing a point" flag.  It's not that he is hated.  He is just not an expert.  He is an activist and should be cited as such if he is ever cited.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your question  was closed as it focuses on a single incident (and possibly the fact countries do not generally allow independent inquiries, ) leading it to look like a 'nudge nudge wink wink question' I'm not all sure if that was the intention. However , your comments here, talking about a question regarding Hamas

> Can any honest and aware person just imagine that somebody can ask a question with this tone about the crimes committed by Israel and UK in Palestine?

is somewhat disturbing

The capture (sic) question seems to be entirely about the dynamics of a stronger Vs weaker opponent.

The Hamas one is clearly asking if there was condemnation of Hamas' tactics. Perfectly fine.